# Render page as a picture

Tags: c#, java, .net, firefox, internet-explorer

I have question to Java or C# programmers. I want to render some pages in various browsers mainly Firefox and IE and save it as a picture. I have not any serious experience in Java/.Net. Is there any libs/tools for such tasks? I thought about some FF extensions for example but I don't know how to do it in IE. Is the in .Net some libs for dealing with it? Maybe some ActiveX? Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://www.vesic.org/english/blog/winforms/render-html-to-quality-jpeg/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but perhaps http://browsershots.org/ offers the functionality you're looking for? It would appear they offer both an [XML-RPC interface](http://api.browsershots.org/xmlrpc/) and also the [source code](http://svn.browsershots.org/) freely.

**Edit:** It looks like the source code link isn't properly hooked up currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FireFox Screengrab extension](http://www.screengrab.org/) - it's very handy!

> "Screengrab! is an extension that
>   makes it easy to save a web-page as an
>   image – it’s a screen capture tool for
>   Firefox!
>
> With it, you can save anything that
>   you can see in a browser window – from
>   a small selection, to a complete
>   page."